# How many ways to assign 10 digits to 6 containers.

Tags: combinatorics

So if we had 6 containers eg (a,b,c,d,e,f) how many ways could we assign the digits 0-9 to these containers. For example one way might be:

a = 4

b = 5

c = 0

d = 3

e = 8

f = 7

Is there a specific formula for this?

Comment: Can each digit be used only once?

Comment: You could try asking the lecturer.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming each digit can be assigned only once:

- 10 digit choices for the first container,
- 9 choices for the second,
- 8 choices for the third,
- 7 choices for the fourth,
- 6 choices for the fifth
- 5 choices for the sixth.

This gives a tree with $10 \cdot 9 \cdots 5$ leaves. As formula it is
$$
\frac{10!}{(10-6)!}
$$
In general, as noted in the comments, this number of ordered draws without repetition of $k$ elements from a set of $n$ elements is called a $k$-permutation of $n$ ([link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation#k-permutations_of_n))
$$
P(n,k) = \frac{n!}{(n-k)!}
$$

Comment: Which is called a combination of n elements taking k, for $n = 10$ and $k=6$.

Comment: @Pirer You mean a permutation.

Comment: @mvw Thanks for the response without giving away the answer!

Comment: @SBareS, a **permutation** is a reordering of elements, whereas **combination** is the usual term when we are chosing $k$ elements among $n$ of them. If there were exactly six digits (i.e. $n = k = 6$), then it would be a permutation problem. You can check that the formula given by mvw coincides in this case with the number of permutations of six elements, $6!$. (It is generally assumed that $0! = 1$.)

Comment: @Pirer In a combination, the order is irrelevant, in a permutation it is not. You can permute a subset (which is what you did) as well as the whole set.

Comment: @SBareS I see, you're absolutely right.